# Is there any way in Elixir to pattern match on a nil argument passed to a function?

Tags: elixir

Is there a way to pattern match on a nil value in a map passed in to a function as an argument?

Basically if token is nil in the below code, I want to pattern match and call function 2.  It doesn't seem like I can do this without writing 2 differently named functions and a case statement.

```
def my_stuff(%{part: "snippets", possible_nil_token: token}), do: IO.puts "non nil"  #function 1

def my_stuff(%{part: "snippets", possible_nil_token: nil}), do: IO.puts "nil"  #function 2
```

Comment: You should accept @HarrisonLucas answer--he's given you the correct answer.

Comment: I use when guards as another option - just for the record.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not exactly sure if I understood you right but basically, the order in which the functions are defined in Elixir is important.

The precedent is top to bottom. This means that the way you defined the functions will always mean that the first function will always match because the value of `token` can be matched to any value.

However, if you swapped them around and had the `nil` checking function, that would get tested first.

E.g.

```
defmodule Match do
  def test(%{part: "snippets", possible_nil_token: nil}), do: IO.puts "nil"
  def test(%{part: "snippets", possible_nil_token: token}), do: IO.puts "non-nil"
end
```

Given the above code, I can easily pass it nil and have it match the first function:

```
iex(1)> Match.test(%{part: "snippets", possible_nil_token: nil})
nil
:ok
iex(2)> Match.test(%{part: "snippets", possible_nil_token: %{val1: "token1"}})
non-nil
:ok
```